# iOS - guided tour with chat bubble-like pop-ups

Tags: ios, uibubbletableview

I want to make a guided tour of my app on the first launch, but not a separated guided tour where I show images of the app. I'd like to have multiple chat-bubbles just like this one:
[image]

And when I click somewhere on the screen, the next one pops up. I haven't found a single tutorial for this on the web, so maybe I'm just not using the right keywords...
Anyways, thanks a lot !

Comment: What code have you already tried? Have you made any attempt at doing this yourself yet? The idea of SO is that you make some sort of attempt at fixing the problem then come here when having trouble with that code. So please share your code

Comment: i suggest you do popviewcontrollers one after another

Comment: @Popeye actually I really wasn't able to find anything but you're right, I should have tried first. Thanks for the suggestions anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an Int e.g. `int firstLaunch` and save it with NSUserDefaults to detect first launch. Then add a view to the UIView in the story board and make it fill the Application screen and give it a grey color and and transparency.
Then add the images of the bubble in the position you want them in the view.

Below would go in the ViewDidLoad:

```
 firstLaunch = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"FirstLaunch"];
 if (firstLaunch == 0) {
       firstLaunch = 1;
       [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:firstLaunch forKey:@"FirstLaunch"];
       ViewName.hidden = NO;
       bubble1Image.hidden = NO;
}
```